# What does a capital letter mean in tablature?

Tags: tablature

What does a capital letter mean in tablature?

I see small q for quarter note. What does capital Q mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a dotted quarter note (length of 3 eighth notes). On the last bar, The bar length changes to 4/4. So, the that bar's note lengths would be quarter, quarter, dotted quarter, and eighth.

Capitalized seems to mean dotted. Am I right to think that the time signature to start was 12/8 or so something like that (6 beats per bar)?

Comment: Ok, thank you.

The only examples I've otherwise seen of a dotted quarter were "q."    .

Example above is from Rush - Limelight.
Found someone who listed all the time changes.

Intro:

6 measures 4/4
4 measures 4+3/4  (this really means 7/4)
Verse:

2 measures 3/4
2 measures 4+2/4
2 measures 3/4
1 measure 4/4
1 measure 4+3/4
Fill 1:

1 measure 4+3/4
Repeat: Verse

Chorus:

7 measures 3/4
8 measures 4/4
Fill 2:

3 of 3/4
2 of 4+3/4
Repeat: Verse, Fill 1, Verse, Chorus

Fill 3:

2 of 4/4
Bridge:

30 measures 3/4
Repeat: Chorus, Fill 3

Ending:
12 of 4/4

Comment: Yea, personally, I've never seen that type of notation before. Also, hot damn that song has a lot of time signature changes lol